# Making a snapshot of ubuntu?

Tags: snapshot

I installed ubuntu without LVM. Is it still possible to make a snapshot of it? If so how can I do it? Keep in mind I never made a linux snapshot before.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, Kernel 4.5

Comment: What's a snapshot??

Answer (score 6):

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

"(Snapshots) is something you simply can not do without LVM"

But not all hope is lost if you have an external hard drive or a file server some where on your network you can use imaging software like http://clonezilla.org/ to create images of your machine and restore to them as your require.

Comment: +1 For citing the wiki. Also Clonezilla is a great backup solution.

Comment: Looks like I am taking this old PC in my closet and turning it into a file server

Comment: @andrew yes clonezilla is great ! Dont forget that you'll need a CD or USB to create a clonezilla image to boot too!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some tools that do just that:

- [TimeShift](https://teejeetech.com/timeshift/)
- [Back In Time](https://github.com/bit-team/backintime)
- [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/)

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is a great cloning tool but it is not designed for snapshots. You can use it that way, but you would probably be better off with a tool providing incremental backups and an in-system interface.

Wikipedia also lists free [backup software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_backup_software) supporting Linux.