# Snapshot for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, restore, snapshot, systemback

I would like to receive recommendations on the most ideal package that can create "restore points" snapshots for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server. Was trying `systemback`but it is not being maintained any more.

Any suggestions please. I would like to have one simple solution that can be scheduled too.

Comment: "most ideal package" is a matter of opinion.  Are you using LVM? https://askubuntu.com/questions/786229/making-a-snapshot-of-ubuntu

Comment: No I am not using LVM

Comment: I would advice to reinstall and start using LVM. Snapshots are an integral part of LVM http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html and http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html

Comment: I am aware of that, but I am after a different solution altogether. Systemback was an ideal package but its no longer maintained and wish to be guided towards a close alternative.